# Cambiar la opacidad de un color background sin afectar al texto que hay encima (css)

Tags: css

Soy nuevo en html/css y estoy intentando colocar un color background sobre un texto y reducir la opacidad ÚNICAMENTE Del color de fondo, pero cuando lo intento no solo cambia la opacidad del fondo, sino que también la del texto. ¿Qué pordía hacer?

```
    <header class="titulo1">     <h1> <b> PRUEBAS DE CSS</b></h1>

    </header>
   </div>


.titulo1{
            background-color: lightblue;
          opacity: 50%;
          }
```

El color background sale con la opacidad del 50%, pero también el título

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar colores [`rgba`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgba) o [`hlsa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsla)

#### Ejemplo:

```css
body {
  background: url('https://estaticos.muyinteresante.es/media/cache/760x570_thumb/uploads/images/test/5af18b675bafe8cd7d3c986b/amigos.jpg')
}
.titulo1 {
  background-color: #add8e68c;
}
.titulo2 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 251, .8);
}
```

```html
<header class="titulo1">
  <h1><b>PRUEBAS DE CSS</b></h1>
</header>
<header class="titulo2">
  <h1><b>PRUEBAS DE CSS 2</b></h1>
</header>
```

---

Referencia:

- [CSS - background-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color)

Comment: Gracias, navegando un poco acabé encontrando la solución, aunque sin saber a ciencia cierta si era la óptima. Tu respuesta me lo ha confirmado 

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad del padre tmb se le aplica a todos los hijos.
Lo que podes probar es declarar la `opacity:50;` al background y a su vez (mas abajo por el efecto cascada), declarar al texto la propiedad de `opacity:100`